# CIFS errors for local user on domain joined ubuntu

Tags: samba, cifs

I have a domain joined ubuntu system. I sometimes Have to log in to the local administrator account. When I do this, I keep getting these messages in journalctl

> May 11 11:21:09 server.domain.com kernel: CIFS VFS: Verify user has a krb5 ticket and keyutils is installed
> May 11 11:21:09 server.domain.com kernel: CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -126

I have an entry in /etc/bash.bashrc that mounts CIFS shares automatically on login except for UID 0 and UID 1000 (local administrator)I thought it was this, but I changed the entry to just echo the UID and I still get the messages. Something somewhere else is trying to mount something somewhere, but I can't seem to find where.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out what was causing the issue. Since we are mounting CIFS shares using krb5 with SSO in Ubuntu, it creates a krb ticket. The ticket is only valid for 10 hours. Some people are leaving their SSH sessions open for much much longer than that. So the ticket expires, but the CIFS share still exists and causes these alerts in syslog. I enabled a timeout on SSH sessions to 8.5 hours and booted all older than today SSH sessions from the server. The alerts seem to have disappeared.